# Python: only appending first if statement, not filling rest of lists

Tags: python, regex, string, split, append

Here is my code:

```
import re

def split_text(text):
    lines = text.split("\n")

    forewing_length = []
    biostatus = []
    distribution_and_frequency = []
    habitat_seasonality_behaviour = []
    life_history = []
    notes = []

    for line in lines:
        match = re.match(r"Forewing length: *(.*?(?=Biostatus|Distribution and frequency|Habitat, seasonality and behaviour|Life history|Notes|$))", line)
        if match:
            forewing_length.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Biostatus"):
            match = re.match(r"Biostatus: *(.*?(?=Distribution and frequency|Habitat, seasonality and behaviour|Life history|Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                biostatus.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Distribution and frequency"):
            match = re.match(r"Distribution and frequency: *(.*?(?=Habitat, seasonality and behaviour|Life history|Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                distribution_and_frequency.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Habitat, seasonality and behaviour"):
            match = re.match(r"Habitat, seasonality and behaviour: *(.*?(?=Life history|Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                habitat_seasonality_behaviour.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Life history"):
            match = re.match(r"Life history: *(.*?(?=Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                life_history.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Notes"):
            match = re.match(r"Notes: *(.*)", line)
            if match:
                notes.append(match.group(1))

    return forewing_length, biostatus, distribution_and_frequency, habitat_seasonality_behaviour, life_history, notes

text = "Forewing length: 2.5–3.5 mm. Biostatus: Endemic. Distribution and frequency: Northern North Island, as far south as Hawke’s Bay and Taranaki. Often abundant, but inconspicuous. Habitat, seasonality and behaviour: Native forest, especially podocarp forest. Adults may be found from late November to March. They fly by day in sunshine, settling briefly on ferns and other vegetation, and have been observed swarming around flow- ering nikau palm. Life history: Very poorly known; larvae have been extracted from moss and from rotting wood. Notes: The family Micropterigidae is an extremely ancient lineage, and the adults retain functional mandibles, unlike all other adult moths. These mandibles are used to chew fern spores and pollen. There is a diverse fauna of 19 species in this family in New Zealand; they are found mostly in moist forest. The forewing pattern of shining white markings in Zealandopterix zonodoxa is variable."

split_text(text)
```

The output is:

```
(['2.5–3.5 mm. '], [], [], [], [], [])
```

The desired output is:

```
(['2.5–3.5 mm.'],
 ['Endemic.'],
 ['Northern North Island, as far south as Hawke’s Bay and Taranaki. Often abundant, but inconspicuous.'],
 ['Native forest, especially podocarp forest. Adults may be found from late November to March. They fly by day in sunshine, settling briefly on ferns and other vegetation, and have been observed swarming around flow- ering nikau palm.'],
 ['Very poorly known; larvae have been extracted from moss and from rotting wood.'],
 ['The family Micropterigidae is an extremely ancient lineage, and the adults retain functional mandibles, unlike all other adult moths. These mandibles are used to chew fern spores and pollen. There is a diverse fauna of 19 species in this family in New Zealand; they are found mostly in moist forest. The forewing pattern of shining white markings in Zealandopterix zonodoxa is variable.'])
```

I am new to coding and first time using re, I know this is probably inefficient and shabby. I also made one with no regex, just heaps of if statements, same issue.

Comment: `text` does not contain any newlines, so `lines = text.split("\n")` will return exactly one line, which means your `for` loop will only run once, and so only one of the output variables will have any contents.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes made:-**

(1)adding `\n` in paragraph `text`

(2)`split_text(text)` into `print(split_text(text))`

**Code:-**

```
import re

def split_text(text):
    lines = text.split("\n")

    forewing_length = []
    biostatus = []
    distribution_and_frequency = []
    habitat_seasonality_behaviour = []
    life_history = []
    notes = []

    for line in lines:
        match = re.match(r"Forewing length: *(.*?(?=Biostatus|Distribution and frequency|Habitat, seasonality and behaviour|Life history|Notes|$))", line)
        if match:
            forewing_length.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Biostatus"):
            match = re.match(r"Biostatus: *(.*?(?=Distribution and frequency|Habitat, seasonality and behaviour|Life history|Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                biostatus.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Distribution and frequency"):
            match = re.match(r"Distribution and frequency: *(.*?(?=Habitat, seasonality and behaviour|Life history|Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                distribution_and_frequency.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Habitat, seasonality and behaviour"):
            match = re.match(r"Habitat, seasonality and behaviour: *(.*?(?=Life history|Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                habitat_seasonality_behaviour.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Life history"):
            match = re.match(r"Life history: *(.*?(?=Notes|$))", line)
            if match:
                life_history.append(match.group(1))
        elif line.startswith("Notes"):
            match = re.match(r"Notes: *(.*)", line)
            if match:
                notes.append(match.group(1))

    return forewing_length, biostatus, distribution_and_frequency, habitat_seasonality_behaviour, life_history, notes

text = "Forewing length: 2.5–3.5 mm.\nBiostatus: Endemic.\nDistribution and frequency: Northern North Island, as far south as Hawke's Bay and Taranaki. Often abundant, but inconspicuous.\nHabitat, seasonality and behaviour: Native forest, especially podocarp forest. Adults may be found from late November to March. They fly by day in sunshine, settling briefly on ferns and other vegetation, and have been observed swarming around flow- ering nikau palm.\nLife history: Very poorly known; larvae have been extracted from moss and from rotting wood.\nNotes: The family Micropterigidae is an extremely ancient lineage, and the adults retain functional mandibles, unlike all other adult moths. These mandibles are used to chew fern spores and pollen. There is a diverse fauna of 19 species in this family in New Zealand; they are found mostly in moist forest. The forewing pattern of shining white markings in Zealandopterix zonodoxa is variable."

print(split_text(text))
```

**Output:-**

```
(['2.5–3.5 mm.'], ['Endemic.'], ["Northern North Island, as far south as Hawke's Bay and Taranaki. Often abundant, but inconspicuous."], ['Native forest, especially podocarp forest. Adults may be found from late November to March. They fly by day in sunshine, settling briefly on ferns and other vegetation, and have been observed swarming around flow- ering nikau palm.'], ['Very poorly known; larvae have been extracted from moss and from rotting wood.'], ['The family Micropterigidae is an extremely ancient lineage, and the adults retain functional mandibles, unlike all other adult moths. These mandibles are used to chew fern spores and pollen. There is a diverse fauna of 19 species in this family in New Zealand; they are found mostly in moist forest. The forewing pattern of shining white markings in Zealandopterix zonodoxa is variable.'])
```